# Cypher Query: Set Property on relationship based off the aggregate of other Property Relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Still getting my feet wet with cyber.

I have the following situation.
Each `BM_RU` relationship has a `FinCYTD` value.
`n` has multiple `BM_RU` relationships to `ru`. 
I am trying to add or set a `bm` property that is the sum of the `FinCYTD` values on those relationships.

```
match (n:BrickMrtr)-[b:BM_RU]->(ru:RU)<-[bm:BM_RU_F]-(n)
where n.Id = '1000829'
with n.Id as bm, sum(toInteger(b.FinCYTD)) as sum_f, ru.RuName as nm, bm.Amt as bm_amt
set bm_amt = sum_f
```

i thought the above would work but i get the following error:

```
Type mismatch: expected Map, Node or Relationship but was Integer (line 5, column 14 (offset: 239))
"set bm_amt = sum_f"
              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
match (n:BrickMrtr)-[b:BM_RU]->(ru:RU)<-[bm:BM_RU_F]-(n)
where n.Id = '1000829'
with n, sum(toInteger(b.FinCYTD)) as sum_f
set bm.amt = sum_f
```

Comment: Tried along those lines to start and got the following  
```
The expression ReferenceFromSlot(0) should have been a node or a relationship, but got String("1000829")
```

Comment: Edited the query. Used with n, ... Please retry.

Comment: No go - the issue i guess is passing the property of bm.amt through the with statement.  that gave error......Variable `bm` not defined (line 4, column 5 (offset: 136))
"set bm.amt = sum_f"
     ^

Comment: got it.  if you are curious you use with to get the second relationship with where and set from there.  looks like this:

match (n:n:BrickMrtr)-[b:BM_RU]->(ru:RU)
where n.BrickMortId = '1000829'
with sum(tointeger(b.FinCYTD)) as sum, ru.RuName  as nm, n.BrickMortId as id
match (z:BrickMrtr)-[bm:BM_RU_F]-(r:RU) 
where r.RuName = nm and z.BrickMortId = id
set bm.amt = sum

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you probably intended:

```
MATCH (n:BrickMrtr)-[b:BM_RU]->(ru:RU)<-[bm:BM_RU_F]-(n)
WHERE n.Id = '1000829'
WITH n, ru, bm, SUM(toInteger(b.FinCYTD)) as sum_f
SET bm.Amt = sum_f
```

You have to assign a value to a *property* (`SET bm.Amt = ...`). You were trying to assign a value to another variable (`SET bm_amt = ...`).

Also, this query uses `n`, `ru`, and `bm` as the grouping keys for the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `SUM`, so that each sum is for a distinct `n`/`ru`/`bm` combination. (I assume that each `ru` only has a single related `bm`.)